# WebSphere Developer Tool 8.5 doesn't support to deploy EJB 2.1

Tags: deployment, ejb, websphere-8

My Dev Env as below.

1. Eclipse Juno with Webshpere Developer tools plugin
2. WebShpere 8.5

I have a project with below facets.

1. EJB Module 2.1
2. Java 1.6
3. WebSphere EJB (Extended) 8.5

When I used "prepare for deployment", there's nothing happened that those stubs class weren't generated. After searching in Internet, I realized that Webshpere Developer tools 8.5 just supports EJB 3.0 or greater.

My project was migrated from WAS6.1 which the tools can support EJB2.0.
Now I don't want to upgrade my project to EJB3.0.
Can anyone help to raise a solution? A extra deployer plugin or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible solutions:

1. Deploy during installation
   You can continue to develop your application in WDT, then export your application as ear. When you install your application to WebSphere, there is an option to Deploy enterprise beans during. If you check that option WebSphere will generate required classes during application installation.
2. Run ejbdeploy command or ant wsejbdeploy ant task.
   Once you have your ear, you can run ejbdeploy commandline tool to generate code, or if you are building your application using ant you can use ant task for this.

   [ejbdeploy command refrence](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.etools.ejbbatchdeploy.doc/topics/regenc.html?lang=en)
   [Older article about using ant tasks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0606_ulbricht/0606_ulbricht.html)
   [Error using Ant to create EJB after upgrading WAS from 6.0 to 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962016/error-using-ant-to-create-ejb-after-upgrading-was-from-6-0-to-7-0)
3. Use IBM Assembly & Deploy Tools for WebSphere Administration v8.5 tool
   If you have WebSphere Application Server license, then you can download additional tool - `IBM Assembly & Deploy Tools for WebSphere Administration v8.5 tool` - this is simplified RAD (Rational Application Developer), based on Eclipse. which will allow you develop your Java EE application and also generate deployment code.
   Here is brief description of functionality of the older version of this tool:
   [Assembly and Deploy Tools](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/topic/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/DevelopmentTools.html?dmuid=20081201174139397807)